# Login is redirected to Session Timeout page using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, password

I'm new to jmeter and would appreciate if someone could help me out on this.

I recorded a script in jmeter from Login to Logout using firefox as my browser. When I checked the input parameters, it is sending out username, password and an encrypted password (AES) before it can log in into the site.

In Welcome.do page it has the code for password encryption (AES/256). In the loginaction.do it returns the parameters along with the masked and encrypted pw (e.g username = testuser1, password = ******, encrypted_password = uicbaicbqibvie20910).

I already tried the boundary expression and it is able to take the encrypted_pw from welcome.do but I noticed that it's not the same as the encrypted_pw(returned from server) when user clicks on Sign In button.

1. How do I masked the pw so that the real pw will not be logged in server.log?
2. How will I get the returned encrypted_pw from server?
3. When I checked the server.log, I also noticed that it seems like jmeter is not able to connect to jboss web server for pw authentication. Is there a configuration that I need to add in order to make the needed connection?

Since it is unable to successfully pass the authentication stage, it is returning a Session Timeout Error and user is unable to login.

So, I try logging in from the website itself and it is able to successfully authenticate my test user account.

What approach should I do in order to resolve this issue?

Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

so you need to **generate** the encrypted password yourself before submitting the credentials. It can be done using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and a piece of [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) replicating the JavaScript used in the Welcome.do page for password encryption.

You can find some samples in [Encryption and decryption with Groovy](https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy) article

Comment: Okay. I'll try to do your suggestion. Are there any pre-requisite before I do this like installing jdbc driver? Do I need to make changes to the jmeter properties file? The only configuration that I did is the JAVA_HOME Path and add the jdk bin in the Path of environment variables in control panel. I also have the certificate. Is there anything else I missed as far as setting up jmeter is concerned?